# PHP get the date in the XML format

Tags: php, xml, datetime

I want to generate the date in XML format from PHP ,

The following is the script that i am looking to generate dynamically:

```
$voice.trackTransactionPageView({
"orderId" : "55555",
"total" : "40.84",
"userId" : "7448dc2",
"email" : "john@example.com",
"nickname" : "john1981",
"deliveryDate" : "2011-01-21T11:36:47.384",
"locale" : "en_US"
});
```

if you see in the above code i have the `deliveryDate` that has the value in xml format so i wanted to generate the same in my code with php.

i have tried with `date('Y-m-dTH:i', time());`

but it's generating `2014-09-29EDT02:28:11`

i am looking to generate `2011-01-21T11:36:47.384.`

Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The date format XML uses is technically [**ISO 8601**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
echo date('c');
```

Result:

```
2014-09-23T10:21:42+00:00
```

Example:

**http://ideone.com/VATp09**